# A program made in Visual Studio 2010 does not work in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem with a program that was made in Visual Studio 2010 and in Visual Studio 2012 is giving me an error. It says that the type `WinForms` does not exist in the type `Microsoft.Reporting`. How can I fix this?

Comment: You would have to be more specific. I assume it displays the error when you try to compile the project? or it happens when you try to open the project with the new version of VS?

Comment: it displays the errowhen i try to compile the project

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to change version no of your cs project to dot that go cs proj open with notepad and edit  ToolsVersion="4.0" to 4.5 and also your your soluntion file eg yourproject.sln open as notepad and edit Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00

## Visual Studio 2010 to Visulal Studio 2012 ,,,thats it

Comment: Sorry but i am new in this, what is the cs project, where do i find it

Comment: go to your project you will see there is folder of your project inside  your project you can see visual studio icon will be there just click on that and open as notepad

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment It appears that there are some missing references in your project.

First thing I'd do is expand the references folder in the solution explorer and look for yellow marked references. if that's the case, you will have to remove these from the project and try to add them again. it appears that you have [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) one missing.

Otherwise I would try to change the runtime to an older version and see if it solves the problem.